# UIStackView Hiding/UnHiding arrangedSubView issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uistackview

I am hiding and unhiding dropDownView(UIView consisting of textfield and button) based on Segment tapped in Segment Control. Following is the view hierarchy :-

[image]

Following is the code which hides/unhides dropDownView :-

```
 private func animateView(view: UIStackView, toHidden hidden: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) 
    {
    let firstView = view.arrangedSubviews[0]
    firstView.isHidden = hidden
    }
    }
func segmentValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        let segmentSelected = segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        switch segmentSelected {
        case 0:
            animateView(view: mainStackView, toHidden: true)
        case 1:
         animateView(view: mainStackView, toHidden: true)
        case 2:
            animateView(view: mainStackView, toHidden: true)
        case 3:
           animateView(view: mainStackView, toHidden: false)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Problem which I am facing is after changing segments over 10-15 times the above code stops working and DropDown View overlaps with Segment Control and I am not sure why. Any help to understand this issue is appreciated.

Also I have already tried 
 **1. setNeedsLayout,

 2. setNeedsDisplay and

 3. reducing priority to height constraint of dropDownView to 999 from
    1000**

Comment: I have noticed that repeatedly hiding or unhiding a view in a stack view seems to be cumulative. Try adding a check for isHidden and only change state if needed: `if view.isHidden { view.isHidden = false }` or `if !view.isHidden { view.isHidden = true }`

Comment: The view is mainStackView. So you mean I need to take outlet for dropDown view and check whether its hidden and then apply ? @Chris

Comment: Yes I think so - there may be another problem, but this worked for me in a simpler context of hiding and unhiding arranged subviews in a stack view in a tableview cell.

Comment: Also your first 3 cases could be represented as `case 0, 1, 2:`

Comment: yea.Will do that. However your suggestion didn't work. After 12 tries it doesn't work again. Thanks for case suggestion.

Comment: Ah ok. I have just submitted an answer including that idea. Could you try it without animating as ‘UIStackView’ should animate `isHidden` changes anyway?

Comment: @Chris - the problem mentioned in your ***first*** comment, I believe they have finally fixed it ("believe it or not") now that it is 2024.  UIStackView still has many, many, many, many, bugs though. It's shit.

Comment: @Fattie That’s good news! I’m now working mainly in SwiftUI now though so I might not get much chance to try it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Seem the additional setting isHidden in completionClosure fixes that issue (Swift 5 syntax):

```
private func animateView(view: UIStackView, toHidden hidden: Bool) {
    let firstView = view.arrangedSubviews[0]
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        firstView.isHidden = hidden
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    } completion {
        firstView.isHidden = hidden
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that sometimes when you hide an `arrangedSubview` it doesn't hide its subviews, so here is the solution (or rather workaround) that works for me (`firstView` and `secondView` here are `arrangedSubviews` of some `UIStackView`):

```
firstView.isHidden = false
firstView.subviews.forEach { $0.isHidden = false }

secondView.isHidden = true
secondView.subviews.forEach { $0.isHidden = true }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without your animate function as stackView should animate hiding and unhiding anyway. Add a check for hidden status and only change it if necessary:

```
func segmentValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    let segmentSelected = segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    let dropDown = mainStackView.arrangedSubviews.first!

    switch segmentSelected {
        case 0, 1, 2:
            if !dropDown.isHidden {
                dropDown.isHidden = true
            }
        case 3:
            if dropDown.isHidden {
                dropDown.isHidden = false
            }
        default:
            break
    }

}
```

Comment: That was already working. I needed to animate the behaviour of drop down hide and unhide. UIView animation as well as transition didn't work. StackView is not animating that behaviour.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I’ll need to think about this one :)

Comment: Np. You don't have to say sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one below. Hope will solve your problem.

```
private func animateView(view: UIStackView, toHidden hidden: Bool) {
    let firstView = view.arrangedSubviews[0]
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        firstView.isHidden = hidden
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: everything works even my mentioned code. keep changing segment 15 times then see if it works then.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the solution that I implemented which seems to work:-

```
private func animateView(view: UIStackView, toHidden hidden: Bool) {
        if !hidden
        {
          mainStackView.insertArrangedSubview(view, at: 0)
          view.isHidden = true
          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            view.isHidden = false
          })
        } else {
            let firstView = mainStackView.arrangedSubviews[0]
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                if firstView == view {
                    firstView.isHidden = true
                }
            }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
                if firstView == view {
                    self?.mainStackView.removeArrangedSubview(firstView)
                    firstView.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Creating DropDown View programmatically (Instead of creating in storyboard) and removing same on every completion. I am not marking this answer correct as its a workaround. I want to understand why storyboard dropDownView fails after 10-15 tries.