# UIStackView add overlapping views in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uikit, uistackview

I added 3 subviews to UIStackView in storyboard. Problem is I need to add a fourth subview which overlaps with the second subview. Only one of the two overlapping subviews will be visible at a time. Is it easy to specify in Storyboard, or I need to add and remove subviews in code?

Comment: You can add 4 views totally and hide & show the 2nd and 4th view whenever needed

Comment: Are you sure hiding a view causes stackview to realign all subviews?

Comment: Yes when you hide one view other views will realign

Comment: Yes do the hiding part in code and it should work fine. Refer this link:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424480/uistackview-hiding-unhiding-arrangedsubview-issue. `Note: Hiding or unhiding a view in a stack view is cumulative.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch between the 2nd or 4th subview on your `UIStackView` you don't need to add or remove subviews, you just need to set the `isHidden` property on them.

A stack view has an additional property `arrangedSubviews`, these are the subviews that the stack view will manage the layout of. If you set `isHidden` to `true` and check the `arrangedSubviews` property you'll see the hidden view has a `height` of `0`. If you check the view debugger, the hidden view is not visible at all in the view hierarchy. The stack view will layout the remaining views according to the properties of the stack view.

This is slightly different to normal views where if a subview's `isHidden` property becomes true, the subview still participates in the view's layout, the contents are just not drawn and it doesn't receive input events.